# Add hyperlink with click event to Dojo grid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

My question is similar to [Implementing a hyperlink within a dojo datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213745/implementing-a-hyperlink-within-a-dojo-datagrid), and I'm successfully able to add markup for hyperlinks to a Dojo grid using a **formatter**.

However, I need to wire up a **click** events on these hyperlinks, to trigger a function within the Dijit containing the grid.

I have a formatter like the following:

```
var createEditLinks = function (data) {
   return '<a class="my-css-class" href="#" onclick="myFunctionInsideTheDijit()">' + data.title + '</a>'
}
```

While this works (I do get the markup inside the grid cell), the **myFunctionInsideTheDijit** function is unavailable (unless I would declare it on the global scope).

I've looked a little at **dom-construct**, but I just can't figure out how to add a hyperlink that invokes a Dijit function when clicked.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more modern way to do this than with `dojo.behavior` would be to use [`on` and event delegation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html#event-delegation).  dgrid instances already expose their own `on` function to make this slightly easier:

```
grid.on('a.my-css-class:click', function (event) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, works like a charm! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Only weird thing is that 'event.target' becomes the inner element of the anchor tag, not the anchor element itself.

Comment: That's expected; `event.target` will be the innermost element that fired the event. `this` will be the element matching the selector.  This is explained in the reference guide page I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to using **dojo/behavior** to make it work:

```
// Code inside Dijit's startup function
var that = this;

behavior.add({
    "a.my-css-class": {
        onclick: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            that.myFunctionInsideTheDijit();
        }
    }
});

behavior.apply();
```

Not sure if there's a more elegant way of doing this? :)

Comment: This appears to be a bit unstable though, I'll keep looking for a better solution...